# Is it considered a bad practice to oversize an array so that negative indices behave well?

Tags: python, programming-practices, coding-style, array

I have been practicing implementing some classic dynamic programming algorithms and was wondering if my implementation of the longest common subsequence search has a significant code smell.

In python, my version of the code is as follows:

```
def calculate_LCS_matrix(S, T):
    '''
    Computes the longest common subsequence of the two input strings

    Args:
        S (str): first input string
        T (str): second input string
    '''    

    # Here is the potentially offending line, I add 1 to both dimensions of the 
    # array so that the array is padded with zeroes on the bottom and right.
    # With this, negative i and j indices simply return 0 from the other side of
    # the array, as desired.
    valuestore = np.zeros((len(S)+1, len(T)+1))

    def LCS(s_char, t_char, i, j):
        '''
        Computes LCS of substrings up to index i and j
        '''

        # Without the array padding, I would have to check special cases for
        # i==0 and j==0
        if s_char == t_char:
            return valuestore[i-1, j-1] + 1
        else:
            return np.max([valuestore[i-1, j], valuestore[i, j-1]])
    for i, s in enumerate(S):
        for j, t in enumerate(T):
            value = LCS(s,t,i,j)
            valuestore[i, j] = value

    return valuestore
```

I am not looking for input on the algorithm itself, just on whether or not it is a bad practice to use this 0-padding space to save lines of code and potential confusion.

If you can give any specific examples of where this  could lead to trouble, I would very much appreciate it!

To help illustrate, the result of running the `calculate_LCS_matrix` function on the strings

"AAABBBBAABB"

and

"AAABBCCAAB"

is this matrix:

```
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  6.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  6.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  7.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

The zero padding around the edges is being used during certain calls to `LCS`.

Comment: No, it is not a bad practice. Used that (in an almost similar manner, but not in Python) 30 years ago to make a fast implementation of Conways "Game of Life".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with it in principle, if you can afford storage space and it makes your life easier.

But I don't personally do it this way, primarily because the guy coming after me (or me, six months later) might think they can actually write legitimate data into those padded rows and columns, and... Kaboom.  Notice how many comments you had to write into your code so that *we* could understand it well enough to answer your question?  You'd have to write those same comments IRL.

So I work out the correct logic for avoiding the array edge instead.

Comment: I very much like the "nothing wrong in principle but you might think twice in practice" argument.  I have personally written a C++ file that was 3/4 comments and only 1/4 code (it was doing a bunch of atomic operations... they're tricksy beasts).  My team and I actually sat down and had a very long discussion of whether or not this was the road we wanted to go down.  In the end, we decided it was the best path forward, but a year later found a way to refactor it to use more standard approaches, and did so immediately.